# Why the `etcd cluster ID mismatch` message is displayed when starting PD?

Tags: distributed-database, tidb, tidb-pd

When I was starting PD (Placement Driver), the `etcd cluster ID mismatch` message displayed for some reason. How to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `--initial-cluster` in the PD startup parameter contains a member that doesn’t belong to this cluster. To solve this problem, check the corresponding cluster of each member, remove the wrong member, and then restart PD.